MOV and resistor selection of smps,flyback converter
I am designing a flyback converter. Input is 60-300 V AC. At the input I am giving a mov and there is a resistor. What is the use of that resistor (10 Ω 2 W)? Will it be acting as a fuse or is it to limit the current flowing through the MOV? If it limits the current wouldn't it obstruct the functioning of the mov? I have an existing design in which that resistor is given after the MOV and before the bridge rectifier. I think I should place it as shown in the image but not sure. The AC supply will be from the main lines so I have used a MOV of 470 V (MPN: PVR-10D471KB). Have I chosen the MOV correctly?



What is the use of that resistor(10 ohm 2Watt) ?

It's a fusible, quite possibly wire-wound, 10Ω-2W resistor. It acts as both an inrush limiter and a fuse.

I think I should place it as shown in the image but not sure .

MOVs can go fail-short if forced to handle the surge currents for long durations. If a MOV goes fail-short it'll short the mains which then results in tripping the breaker. So it's better to place the fuse before the MOV to protect it.

Why not then use a fuse itself , If the resistor wattage is breached then resistor will fail as open but it might also catch fire , which is dangerous right? I am using it for industrial application ie in a factory , fire will be very risky , Is there any better reason because i am thinking to remove it

@rachitjuthani - Although you're asking Rohat Kılıç, I'll reply in case he's busy. "Why not then use a fuse itself" The answer already explains that it's acting as an inrush limiter too, not just a fuse. "it might also catch fire" It should not do that, as it must be a special fusible type. Look on the schematic, its refdes is RF1 - F=fusible (research the term "fusible resistor"). "i am thinking to remove it" That's a bad plan, IMHO. || As it now seems the schematic in the question was copied from elsewhere, please comply with the site rule for referencing.

@SamGibson
Thank you so much, I can't exactly share the source of the design , As I was given this by  someone else, But I am 90% confident it is generated from Power Intergrations website,

@rachitjuthani Sam already answered your questions (thanks) but I have something to add: If you remove RF1 you'll end up with an unprotected MOV which, as explained in my answer, may fail short in case of a repetitive surge. You can replace it with a regular fuse but the inrush limiting feature will be lost. The target environment is industrial and you probably don't know the breaker properties, so when this circuit is turned on the excessive inrush current (e.g. 100 A peak) may trip the breaker. This is not a desired behaviour in an industrial environment.
